# Web and Application tier on Azure Web apps

Tags: azure-web-app-service

We have a 3 tier .Net application application that we want to migrate into cloud in 'cloud native'. Any reference architecture that can be use.

Also, will web and application tier be deployed as a separate web apps or application/API will be on some different app type within same VNet?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep tiers on same vnet and different subnets . and connect them with application gateway and loadbalancer's as show in below artical .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/n-tier/n-tier-sql-server

Comment: Thanks but your reference provides more of a 'Lift and Shift' approach. I am looking for a 'Cloud Native' approach.